# Nuxt local json file is not loading in deployment

Tags: json, vue.js, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a json file stored in static folder of a nuxt project.

```json
{
  "volvo": {
     "brand": "Volvo"
     "model": "v60",
     "price": 36150,
   },
  "lexus": {
     "brand": "Lexus",
     "model": "is-250-c",
     "price": 36150,
  },
  ....
}
```

Imported this json file inside of a page
`pages/cars/_car.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1> {{ carInfo.brand }} </h1>
    <p>Model: {{ carInfo.model }} </p>
    <p>Price: {{ carInfo.price }} </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 const carList = () => import('~/static/cars.json').then(m => m.default || m)

 export default {
   name: 'Car',
   async asyncData({params, redirect}) {
     const cars = await carList()
     if (!cars[params.car]) {
        redirect('/')
     }
     const carInfo = cars[params.car]
     return {
       carInfo,
       params.car
     }
   }
 }


</script>
```

This page renders without any error locally and I get no errors.
`http://localhost:3000/cars/volvo`

But when it's deployed to Netlify, I get error on console that `title` is `undefined`. Even when I console logged `carList` data, I get nothing in console after deployment.
It seems like that the json file is not being imported after nuxt generate.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'test_app',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/stylelint
    '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
    baseURL: '/',
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you build it locally?

Comment: Yes, it works locally

Comment: What if you edit the code to only use `async/await` here (and use it directly in your asyncData)? Also, maybe try to install Netlify's CLI to work with their dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nuxt/vue v2 you should consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store `enums`.

Comment: Not sure if it's related.

Comment: @kissu this is exactly what Vuex is for. Just store the `enum` in the store state instead of a static json file.

Comment: Vuex is a global store, not a JSON loader per-se.

Comment: @kissu would it not make sense to store this JSON data in the store?

Comment: Maybe. This is not the main issue that OP faces tho.